# How to find files by words inside parentheses in filenames?

Tags: find, filenames

I have a bunch of files with filenames like `Matroid (bifrons's conflicted copy 2019-11-19).scala` due to problems of synchronization. I want to find this files to remove or manually correct the problems (merge the two versions of the file). I tried the command below:

```
$ find . -iname '*conflicted*'
```

But it returns nothing! Nada!

I am guessing this is because the word `conflicted` occurs inside parentheses, but this is just a conjecture. Anyway, why my command do not find the files? How can I find them?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks ok and works for me. What OS and `find` version are you using? Are you running this command in the correct directory?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and find 4.7.0. I am confident I am running find in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem had nothing to do with parentheses at all. It as a (silly) mistake of mine. The directory containing the files with the `*conflicted*` filename was actually a link and `find` does not follow links by default. After informing the option `-L` it worked perfectly.